# Issue searching the available BLE devices in android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

We have an android application for scanning and connecting to BLE devices. Everything works fine, but in some cases, The application is listing the available ble devices only if we install nRF connect application. This is mainly happening in brand new tablets. Below are the permissions granted.  Our application is supporting from Android 10 and above. The issue was noticed in S8 with android 13.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES"/>
```

Comment: You mean that your own application only scans BLE devices properly if the nRF Connect app happens to be installed (but not running) on the same phone/tablet?

Comment: yes, but in some devices

Comment: The list does not contain the granted permissions, only  the permissions you declared in your manifest. Some of these are runtime permissions and need to be requested by the app. Have you encountered this problem with other Android versions?